# Is it secure mechanism of sharing data?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I need to share a file with some users. Using the way described below. Is it secure to share keys?

1. I have a data file.
2. I will encrypt a file, using any algorithm(GPG, OpenSSL).
3. Before encrypt I create keys private and public.
4. Then I upload a file to public storage.
5. If someone will find a file, and download it, he couldn't read encrypted file.
6. If I share my keys (private or public key?) with someone whom I want to share, he could decrypt use the same algorithm with my key.

Is it secure to share a key to decrypt a file?

Comment: You accept that encryption works, right? Suppose you used OpenSSL `smime` command? What specifically are you worried about?

Comment: This question is somewhat confusing.  The information is only secure as long as the private key is known only to you.  If anyone else knows the private key, then by definition, it is no longer secure...

Comment: If you are generating the key to transmit together with the file, you don't need public/private crypto at all; a simple symmetric key will do just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to share an encrypted file with someone, that intended recipient would give you their public key.  You would encrypt it with the recipient's public key and only the recipient would be able to decrypt it with their private key.

Generally, no, it is not secure to share a key.

Other things to consider:

1. Public/Private keys can only encrypt a small amount of data by themselves.  Generally they are used to encrypt symmetric keys that are used to encrypt/decrypt the payload.  Using GPG etc would likely generate a "file" for you that has the symmetric key encrypted with the recipient's public key as well as the symmetrically encrypted payload.  The recipient decrypts with their private key.
2. When you get your intended recipient's public key, how can you be sure the public key came from your recipient?  Read up on the concept of [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for some things to consider.